# Only show the subcategories related to the category in select option laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, html-select

I want to show only the subcategories related to the category chosen prior using dynamic select dropdown in laravel.

here's my code

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Category</label>
        <select id="categoryList" class="form-control" name="category_id" required>
            @foreach ($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>

        <label>Subcategory</label>
        <select id="subcategoryList" class="form-control" name="subcategory_id" required>
            @foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory)
                <option value="{{ $subcategory->id }}">{{ $subcategory->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
```

any help is greatly appreciated TIA!

Edited*

Here is the model for the category and subcategory

Category

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model

{
    public $timestamps = false;

public function subcategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory');
}
}
```

Subcategory

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subcategory extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the models, schema of both the categories.

Comment: Hi Aashish! I've already edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list is not too big or no need ajax, usually I do add `category_id` as a class on subcategory option then hide it until the parent category selected.

assuming your relation column to category is `category_id` the code would be like below:

```
<label>Subcategory</label>
<select id="subcategoryList" class="form-control" name="subcategory_id" required disabled>
    @foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory)
        <option value="{{ $subcategory->id }}" class='parent-{{ $subcategory->category_id }} subcategory'>{{ $subcategory->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

and here jquery to do it:

```
$('#categoryList').on('change', function () {
    $("#subcategoryList").attr('disabled', false); //enable subcategory select
    $("#subcategoryList").val("");
    $(".subcategory").attr('disabled', true); //disable all category option
    $(".subcategory").hide(); //hide all subcategory option
    $(".parent-" + $(this).val()).attr('disabled', false); //enable subcategory of selected category/parent
    $(".parent-" + $(this).val()).show(); 
});
```

Comment: YUP! this works thanks Muhammad! I'll just tweak your code a little to my preference. you've been a great help brother